# Javascript string syntax and for loop logic

Tags: javascript

So i am learning how to perform loops with javascript, and was researching how to  do it with an array. I understand how to create arrays, but what i am not clear on is using implementing that in the loop. So i cam across examples that kind of "manufacture an array within the loop" as i think i have done in this case.

What i want to do is use javascript to change the classes of different dom elements on a page. What i don't want to do is repeat the same code over and over again with a different numerical value. I thought i had everything right but apparently i don't. Here is my code:

```
<script>
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    var storyImageSubmit + [i] = document.getElementById('story_image_' + [i]);
    var realImageUpload + [i] = document.getElementById('realImageUpload' + [i]);

    realImageUpload + [i].addEventListener('mouseover', over_profile_image_submit_ + [i], false);
    realImageUpload + [i].addEventListener('mouseout', out_profile_image_submit_ + [i], false);
    realImageUpload + [i].addEventListener('mousedown', down_profile_image_submit_ + [i], false);
    realImageUpload + [i].addEventListener('mouseup', up_profile_image_submit_ + [i], false);

    function over_profile_image_submit_ + [i] + () {
        storyImageSubmit + [i].className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmitHover"; 
    }
    function out_profile_image_submit_ + [i] + () {
        storyImageSubmit + [i].className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmit"; 
    }
    function down_profile_image_submit_ + [i] + () {
        storyImageSubmit + [i].className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmitDown"; 
    }
    function up_profile_image_submit_ + [i] + () {
        storyImageSubmit + [i].className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmit"; 
    }
}
</script>
```

What i want the code to look like, but iterated with the different numerical values of 1-10, is this:

```
<script>
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    var storyImageSubmit1 = document.getElementById('story_image_1');
    var realImageUpload1 = document.getElementById('realImageUpload1']);

    realImageUpload1.addEventListener('mouseover', over_profile_image_submit_1, false);
    realImageUpload1.addEventListener('mouseout', out_profile_image_submit_1, false);
    realImageUpload1.addEventListener('mousedown', down_profile_image_submit_1, false);
    realImageUpload1.addEventListener('mouseup', up_profile_image_submit_1, false);

    function over_profile_image_submit_1() {
        storyImageSubmit1.className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmitHover"; 
    }
    function out_profile_image_submit_1() {
        storyImageSubmit1.className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmit"; 
    }
    function down_profile_image_submit_1() {
        storyImageSubmit1.className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmitDown"; 
    }
    function up_profile_image_submit_1() {
        storyImageSubmit1.className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmit"; 
    }
}
</script
```

what am i doing wrong here?

<----------------------UPDATE:----------------------->

this is my code presently, after determining that i need an array to accomplish what i want to do. I tested my loop of my array variable, and everything in that department seems to be working fine.

The next issue i have run into now is getting javascript not to rewrite over my listening variables defined by each iteration. I decided the best way to do that would be to eliminate any variables in the loop so that each listening and function execution is unique. I am doing that with the assumption that rewriting my variables is why it wont work. but even after doing that, it won't work.

```
<script>
var storyImageValue = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
for (var i = 0; i < storyImageValue.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('realImageUpload' + storyImageValue[i]).addEventListener('mouseover', function () { document.getElementById('storyImageSubmit' + storyImageValue[i]).className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmitHover"; }, false);
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I recommend whatever solution you come to, post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and get some feedback.

Comment: you've got to be clear that you're not actually using nor needing an array at all in this situation.

Comment: As per your update, I've updated my answer to explain the issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var storyImage = document.getElementById('story_image_' + i);
    var realImage = document.getElementById('realImageUpload' + i);

    realImage.addEventListener('mouseover', function () { storyImage.className = "..."; }, false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: this wont hold that variables for the listeners as it iterates through   , right? I need to have the listeners remain after each definition. Also, apparently i need to be using an array of the numbers within quotes so that they can be attached properly in the string.

For example: 

instead of using "var i = 1;" i need to use "var i = '1';" which will remove the functionality of the loop with 'i++'

Comment: @willy: You don't need to have the numbers as strings no, because when concatenating a string with a number in JavaScript, the number will be automatically coerced to a string.

Comment: you are correct. Just tested that. I am not sure what the issue was with that

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array in JavaScript, this is how you can iterate it with a for-loop construct:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3], i, element;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    element = arr[i];
    // Now do whatever you want with element within this loop.
}
```

---

**Update** as per your comment:

What's happening in the code you have in the comment is that the variable `i` is not being scoped properly for your purposes.  Thing is, in JavaScript, there's no block scope, only function scope...

This means that whenever your event listener function is being invoked, it's getting the value of `i` but that value is always going to be the last value that was used in the loop..in this case, 10.

Try it like this:

```
var storyImageValue = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

for (var i = 0; i < storyImageValue.length; i++) {
  (function (index) {
    document.getElementById('realImageUpload' + storyImageValue[index]).addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        document.getElementById('storyImageSubmit' + storyImageValue[index]).className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmitHover";
    }, false);
  }(i));
}
```

What I'm doing is I'm creating a function that takes a single argument (representing the loop index in our case) which invokes itself immediately after being declared, passing in the current value of the loop counter `i`.

This is because of what I mentioned before as regards scoping.  Since JavaScript does not support block scoping, but only function scoping, creating a function which immediately invokes itself will create the scope you need to store the loop counter so that once your event listener function is executed, it will access the correct value.

Comment: So I figured out i need an array for this to work but something within my loop isnt working properly.    `var storyImageValue = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
for (var i = 0; i < storyImageValue.length; i++) {
document.getElementById('realImageUpload' + storyImageValue[i]).addEventListener('mouseover', function () { document.getElementById('storyImageSubmit' + storyImageValue[i]).className = "accountSettingsBrowseSubmitHover"; }, false);}`

Comment: Ah, you've just been bitten by closures.  Updated the answer to tackle your issue.

Comment: Also, since you're simply storing consecutive numbers in your array, might as well make use of the loop counter directly, i.e. eliminate the array completely and then just do `'realImageUpload' + index`.

Comment: This is working, but only for the first iteration. When i go in the html and change the id to a later number, it wont work for that id. I tested it and because after executing the function it is exiting the loop. And in this case i guess you're right. It is better to do it by stringing on the index value rather than array values.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can use below syntax for parsing javascript array :

$.each(curVal, function(i, array){

alert (curVal);
        });